# How to change anchor in column using text in another column?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the anchor(s) on my second column to have a link that includes information from my first and third column.

How can we do this using Jquery?

Please see example below:

How do I go from this:

```
<table>
<tr><th>Model Id</th><th>Model Num(s)</th><th>Company</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td><a>Model-1</a></td><td><span>Apple</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td><a>Model-2</a></td><td><span>MS</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td><a>Model-3</a><a>Model-4</a><a>Model-5</a></td><td><span>IBM</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

to This:

```
<table>
<tr><th>Model Id</th><th>Model Num(s)</th><th>Company</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td><a href="models/model-1.html?&id=1&div=Apple">Model-1</a></td><td><span>Apple</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td><a href="models/model-2.html?&id=2&div=MS">Model-2</a></td><td><span>MS</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td><a href="models/model-3.html?&id=3&div=IBM">Model-3</a><a   href="models/model-4.html?&id=4&div=IBM">Model-4</a><a href="models/model-5.html?&id=5&div=IBM">Model-5</a></td><td><span>IBM</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Uh...was your intention to have everything on a single line, or did you accidentally leave out a number of `<tr> elements`? The arrangement of data in your table is currently rather visually confusing.

Comment: Sorry you are correct..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('table tr td:nth-child(2) a').each(function() {
    var link = $(this); 
    var siblings = link.parent().siblings();
    var id = siblings.eq(0).text();
    var div = siblings.eq(1).text();
    var href = 'models/' + link.text().toLowerCase() + '.html?&id=' + id + '&div=' + div;
    link.attr('href', href);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the structure of the HTML will be consistent (first row is a header row, and the number of columns never varies), the script below should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Go through each <tr> after the first one
    $("table tr:gt(0)").each(function(){
        currRow = $(this);
        var id = currRow.find("td:nth-child(1)").text();
        var div = currRow.find("td:nth-child(3)").text();

        // Assemble final href for each link in current row
        currRow.find("a").each(function(){
            var model = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            var finalHref = "models/" + model + ".html?&id=" + id + "&div=" + div;
            $(this).attr("href", finalHref);
        });
    });
});
```

This script iterates through each `<tr>` element after the first, and sets the `href` of each child anchor tag it finds based on the content of that `<tr>`. Here's a [JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/F9mFj/3/).

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.